# str_replace() change dot with dashes automaticly

Tags: php, str-replace

I have an HTML file with this string `{userName}`.
on the PHP function I use str_replace() to replace `userName` with a variable.

```
$var = "example.example";
$template = file_get_contents($templateFile);

$template = str_replace("{userName}", $var , $template);
```

the problem is `str_replace` replaces dots with dashes!

```
it returns --> $template = example-example
```

Comment: What's the content of `$templateFile`?

Comment: @Milad                                 <td class="chart" align="left">{userName}</td>

Comment: [Tested your code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c686428639c5095bd7abba411f0cad8732c8b6b2), with your input, and it returns `<td class="chart" align="left">example.example</td>` as expected. PHP 7.3.25.

Comment: Works in all versions https://3v4l.org/4RC20

Comment: This `str_replace()` won't do that. Something else is doing it.